# Checking for TPM readiness with WMI and VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript, wmi, tpm

If I am using this [WMI method '.IsEnabled'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376454(v=vs.85).aspx)  should I be concerned with how I am handling the results in my if statement. If a method returns a bool value can I still use a Not or should I do something like

```
if myStatus <> 0 OR isTPMEnabled <> True then
```

Here is my code

```
function isTPMReadyToBeOwned(myTPMService)
        dim myStatus, isTPMEnabled, isTPMActivated, isTPMOwnershipAllowed

        myStatus = myTPMService.IsEnabled(isTPMEnabled)
        if myStatus <> 0 or not(isTPMEnabled) then
            oLogging.CreateEntry "TPM isn't enable and must be enabled and activated manually, errorcode " & Hex(myStatus), LogTypeWarning
            isTPMReadyToBeOwned = False
            exit Function
        end If

        myStatus = myTPMService.IsActivated(isTPMActivated)
        If myStatus <> 0 or not(isTPMActivated) then
            oLogging.CreateEntry "TPM isn't active and must be activated manually, errorcode " & Hex(myStatus), LogTypeWarning
            isTPMReadyToBeOwned = False
            exit Function
        end If

        myStatus = myTPMService.isOwnershipAllowed(isTPMOwnershipAllowed)
        if myStatus <> 0 or not(isTPMOwnershipAllowed) then 
            oLogging.CreateEntry "TPM ownership is not allowed, errorcode " & Hex(myStatus), LogTypeWarning
            isTPMReadyToBeOwned = False
            exit Function
        end If

        isTPMReadyToBeOwned = True
    end Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean expressions/variables shouldn't be compared to boolean literal, because it adds an extra level of complexity (operator and operand). So use `Not isTPMEnabled`. As `Not` is neither a function nor an array, don't use param list/index (); reserve () for cases of precedence override.

**Update wrt comment:**

() have (too) many functions in VBScript

1. parameter list () in function calls: x = f(y, z)
2. index (): a = SomeArray(4711)
3. precedence override: 2 + 3 * 4 = 14, (2 + 3) * 5 = 25

() in boolean expression should be of type 3 only.

Comment: Dont understand your last sentence, " don't use param list/index (); reserve () for cases of precedence overwrite."